# Unable to show list in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to show the list in RecyclerView.
but after setting adapter only Adapter constructor getting called after that nothing happens

Below is the code of Adapter

```
    public class ChildNameAdpator extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildNameAdpator.ViewHolder> {

    List<ChildDatum> arrayList;


    public ChildNameAdpator(List<ChildDatum> arrayListChildName) {
         arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList = arrayListChildName;
     }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChildNameAdpator.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         LinearLayout layoutRowPermissionCount = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_child_name_layout, parent, false);
         return new ViewHolder(layoutRowPermissionCount);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChildNameAdpator.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.mTvChildName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getChildName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        AutoResizeTextView mTvChildName;
        LinearLayout mLinearLayoutChild;
        AutoResizeTextView imageButtonDeleteChildRow;


        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Log.d(TAG, "ViewHolder: ");
            mTvChildName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_row_child_name);
            mLinearLayoutChild = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_row_child_name);

        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this adapter with below code

```
mRecyclerviewChildName = findViewById(R.id.rv_child_name_parental_control);
    mRecyclerviewChildName.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


  mCurrentChildsList.add(new ChildDatum("11", "ty8902", "3333", "3333", "333", "2222", "2222", "1222"));
        mCurrentChildsList.add(new ChildDatum("12", "ty8902", "3333", "3333", "333", "2222", "2222", "1222"));
        mCurrentChildsList.add(new ChildDatum("13", "ty8902", "3333", "3333", "333", "2222", "2222", "1222"));

        childNameAdpator = new ChildNameAdpator(mCurrentChildsList);
        mRecyclerviewChildName.setAdapter(childNameAdpator);
```

Below is row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_row_child_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT: Added Recyclerview's Parent Layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_display_child_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_child_name_parental_control"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            <com.lb.auto_fit_textview.AutoResizeTextView
                android:id="@+id/ib_add_new_child_name"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGreyLight"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

After `setAdapter` only constructor getting called nothing else that's it.

I thought it is due to my Gradle issue and tried on another laptop, the same issue occurred there.

Looking for help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you setting LayoutManager like this? `RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

Comment: Why your Adapter class is private? it should be public.

Comment: Thanks but no luck, even if I make it public it doesn't matter here, I have tried.

Comment: add your RecyclerView's parent xml code

Comment: Please check updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got my mistake.

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

VISIBILITY of parent Cardview was GONE due to this onBindViewHolder was not getting called.
When I changed the visibility to VISIBLE it Worked.

Thank you all for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Change Adapter Constructor and try this

```
public ChildNameAdpator(List<ChildDatum> arrayListChildName) {
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.addAll(arrayList);
 }
```

or

```
public ChildNameAdpator(List<ChildDatum> arrayListChildName) {
this.arrayList = arrayListChildName;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have skipped the LayoutManager.

A `LayoutManager` is responsible for measuring and positioning item views within a RecyclerView as well as determining the policy for when to recycle item views that are no longer visible to the user.

Set the LayoutManager once you initialized the recycler view.

```
mRecyclerviewChildName.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Reference : [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager)

Adapter Code:

```
public class ChildNameAdpator extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildNameAdpator.ViewHolder> {

private List<ChildDatum> arrayList;


public ChildNameAdpator(List<ChildDatum> arrayListChildName) {
    arrayList = arrayListChildName;
}
}
```

This how your adapter class looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
Main Activity.

    public class DemoTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView mRecyclerviewChildName;
    ChildNameAdpator childNameAdpator;
    List<ChildDatum> mCurrentChildsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo_test);

        mCurrentChildsList = new ArrayList<>();
        mRecyclerviewChildName=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_child_name_parental_control);

        mCurrentChildsList.add(new ChildDatum("Mehul"));
        mCurrentChildsList.add(new ChildDatum("Mehul 1"));
        mCurrentChildsList.add(new ChildDatum("Mehul 2"));

        childNameAdpator = new ChildNameAdpator(mCurrentChildsList);
        mRecyclerviewChildName.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(DemoTestActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        mRecyclerviewChildName.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerviewChildName.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        mRecyclerviewChildName.setAdapter(childNameAdpator);

    }}


Main Layout file 

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DemoTestActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_child_name_parental_control"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

   </RelativeLayout>


Adapter 

        public class ChildNameAdpator extends 
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildNameAdpator.ViewHolder> {

    List<ChildDatum> arrayList;


    public ChildNameAdpator(List<ChildDatum> arrayListChildName) {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList = arrayListChildName;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChildNameAdpator.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LinearLayout layoutRowPermissionCount = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_child_name_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(layoutRowPermissionCount);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChildNameAdpator.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTvChildName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getChildName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mTvChildName;
        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTvChildName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_row_child_name);
        }

    }}

Model class  
    public class ChildDatum {

String ChildName;

public ChildDatum(String sChildName) {
    this.ChildName = sChildName;
}

public String getChildName() {
    return ChildName;
}

public void setChildName(String childName) {
    ChildName = childName;
}}
```

Comment: Share your row_child_name_layout file.

Comment: is it necessary, Adapter is not going beyond Constructor, not even in OnCreateViewHolder

Comment: Please check it. I have updated my code. It's working for me. Hope its working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
    rView=findViewById(R.id.rView);
    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    lManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lManager);
```

Comment: Change return new ViewHolder(layoutRowPermissionCount); for return new ChildNameAdpator.ViewHolder(layoutRowPermissionCount);

Comment: I have just made these changes but no luck,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following things you have done:

1. Declared your adapter class as public
2. Initialised
   'mCurrentChildsList' before adding items.

**Initialise**: mCurrentChildsList = new ArrayList()